# Maven pom error

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, projects

I have example projects from spring core training courses I've been on. They did work on their machines, not on mine though. I am not really expert with maven, but .pom file inside gives this error. I really appreciate any monkey-alike-instructions, I'l do first then understand. Thank you very much in advance. I just want to run them and go through again.

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer com.springsource.training.common:abstractWebProject:pom:1.1.7.RELEASE from https://tbits.springsource.com/repository/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of com.springsource.training.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced.

Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.springsource.training.common:abstractWebProject:pom:1.1.7.RELEASE from/to com.springsource.training.snapshot (https://tbits.springsource.com/repository/snapshot): ConnectException and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM pom.xml /mvc-1-solution line 1  Maven Problem

plus I am having numerous mistakes for missing libraries:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

```
Project 'mvc-1-solution' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\Blabla\.m2\repository\org\cloudfoundry\cloudfoundry-runtime\0.6.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT\cloudfoundry-runtime-0.6.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar' mvc-1-solution      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'mvc-1-solution' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\Blabla\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-annotations\3.5.3-Final\hibernate-annotations-3.5.3-Final.jar'    mvc-1-solution      Build path  Build Path Problem
Project 'mvc-1-solution' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\Blabla\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.5.3-Final\hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar'  mvc-1-solution      Build path  Build Path Problem
```

and many more alike.

**Their .pom file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.springsource.training.module</groupId>
<artifactId>mvc-1-solution</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.springsource.training.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>abstractWebProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.training.snapshot</id>
        <name>SpringSource Training Repository - Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://tbits.springsource.com/repository/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.training.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Training Repository - Releases</name>
        <url>https://tbits.springsource.com/repository/release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://s3.amazonaws.com/private.maven.springsource.com/snapshot/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <!-- DBCP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- CloudFoundry -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm not convinced those repositories exist in a publicly-available way. Trying to access the S3 repo returns an access error, too.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'l have to deal with it somehow. Im rewriting .pom, not really experienced, but you never know until you try. In STS how do you resolve missing libraries without really going into pom?

Comment: What's STS? And you rarely need to add *every* dependency, that what Maven does *for* you--handle the transitives.

Comment: Spring Tool Suite based on Eclipse. I guess I have to run through tutorials or search some knowledge. Do you all configure maven through command line, is there a way to press "some magical button" in Eclipse, so that everything will be added automatically :)?

Comment: How would it know what "everything" was? The dependencies depend on your project's needs.

Comment: How? It sees that I import library which doesn't exist and it searches and then downloads it and automatically adds it to my project. :-) I am not really into discussing that, it was somewhat of a irony joke on my side. I would really appreciate if you would tell me please steps you do when creating projects with maven. At least the top level, very general steps(I will support myself with tutorials, but want to know real life experts way of doing this), I am struggling to learn on my own. Thank You.

Comment: I create a POM file and as I need dependencies I add them to the POM. I add dependencies at the highest possible level of abstraction, so that Maven does most of the work, e.g., if I need Spring, I add the most-abstract component, which will transitively require both lower-level Spring, and third-party, dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but a recipe how to solve it:

- Check each of the repositories you have defined in the Maven POM. For me, the 2 springsource repos are not available at the moment.
- I think that the `abstractWebProject` will be contained in some of these. So the error `Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer` will be a result of that.
- After you may have access to the parent POM, you should check if all the dependencies are resolvable.
- If everything fails, get in touch with the training team. If you were on that training, they will try to help you. You should have then the following information ready available:

  - The POM you want to use (as in your question)
  - The file `settings.xml` in your Maven installation
  - The version of your Maven isntallation
  - The file `settings.xml` in your user directory `.m2` (depending on your operating system at different locations).

Hope you can get the help you need to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

"..resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of com.springsource.training.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced." --This is due to the first failure trying to download artifacts, need to remove those *.lastUpdated from your repository.

For windows:

cd %userprofile%.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i